# In-App billing V3, how do i track the purchased items before consuming?

Tags: android

I am implementing In-App billing feature to sell a digital content.

I want one of the feature in our app to be available only for the paid users (via In-App purchase); we expect the user to purchase only once.

When user installs the App for the first time, how can i track if the user has already purchased an item(feature) or not..
Since it is not consumable, I am not consuming the item after purchase..

If i consume, it is easy to track by requesting the owned products..
If i do not consume, but i have purchased, google play will not allow me to purchase again.. this is fine..
But how do i track the same when user installs the App for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Your server will keep track of this thing, now follow the scenarios given below

1. User first time come to the app
   App will make a server call asking purchase status definitely as it is first time arrival ask him to purchase features.
2. Now user purchase that item, update item purchase status to your own server
3. Now again user come to that flow App will make a server call asking purchase status, if item purchased show him purchase features or if not purchased ask him to purchase features/item.

Note: If you have no server you keep that in local db or shared preferences but in case of clear data or uninstall user information and purchase information will lost.

Comment: I do not want to keep that in local db or shared preferences.
But maintaining the purchase info in server is the only way? don't we have any other options..we do not want to maintain a server just for this purpose..

Comment: No there is no native API to provide you that information before initiating purchase.